# Url rewriting in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

i'm working on asp.net web application.

please guide me for url rewriting in asp.net:

i need to change below link

```
http://www.faredepot.com/ViewArticle.aspx?aid=1
```

to

```
http://www.faredepot.com/Cheap_Flights_to_Atlanta.html
```

how can i achieve this i tried like following

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();

        if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("http://www.faredepot.com/Cheap_Flights_to_Atlanta.html")) {
            Context.RewritePath("http://www.faredepot.com/ViewArticle.aspx?aid=1");
        }
    }
```

or else trying to do it in web.config

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="http://www.faredepot.com/ViewArticle.aspx?aid=1" to="http://www.faredepot.com/Cheap_Flights_to_Atlanta.htm" />
</rewriter>
```

Comment: Are you using VS 2010? If you are, ASP.NET Routing is the best option, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: Great, go with ASP.NET Routing. Also, I've written a Navigation project that will help, http://navigation.codeplex.com/ . If you're interested and want any help, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an excellent breakdown of all the possible solutions here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Which version of IIS are you using? For IIS7 use its own URL Rewrite Module, and for II6 use Intelligencia UrlRewriter.NET: http://urlrewriter.net/